# Centos 8 remote X11 desktop

Tags: x11, centos8, wayland, x11-forwarding

Centos 8 ships with Wayland as its compositor and I was forced to install centos8 due to some GLIBCXX compatability issue. Everything SEEMS to work ok but there is a curious absence of all xapps and I cant get a remote X11 session going. It seems I am in Wayland hell.

Centos 8 ships with the shiny new Wayland with rumored X11 compatibility, but all I find is articles on rumors of xwayland and a host of badly named products whose names all begin with 'W' for cute.

I cant seem to install any x11, xapps or anything that would force xwayland to install as a dependency. Its amazing how easily a decision is taken to burn thousands of hours on tens of thousands of users globally.

My best google-fu has yielded nothing.

Please help. How can I get x11 (xwayland) up and running so that I can run apps from my Windows desktop as I used to with Centos 7...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already encountered this "problem" and the solution I usually apply is to disable WayLand.

To do this, just edit this file with any editor (I use VI)

> /etc/gdm/custom.conf

and change the line

> #WaylandEnable=false

into

> WaylandEnable=false

Save and close the file and restart gdm service with

> systemctl restart gdm.service

Comment: I wont be doing this and I learned to live with the new reality - but I thank you for your reply and have credited you accordingly.